# Trouble with input mask javascript RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm masking an input (using outsystems) to accept only letters. But it should also accept special characters like: `ã`, `é`, `õ`, `â`, etc...
It must be 250 characters long.

I've tried many ways and ended up using this function:

```
$('.nome').mask('A#', {'translation': { A: {pattern: /[^0-9]+/}}});
```

That: `/[^0-9]+/` only accept 1 char. How could it be in the right way?
Thanks!

Comment: It is not possible that `[^0-9]+` matched 1 char. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD1lI8/1). Are you sure you only want letters? Then try `XRegExp` with `^\\pL+$` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`XRegExp`](http://xregexp.com/syntax/) to test if a string only contains Unicode letters:

```js
var str = "Jãnétterõmâ";
var regex = XRegExp('^\\p{L}{0,250}$');
console.log(regex.test(str));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xregexp/2.0.0/xregexp-all-min.js"></script>
```

The `^\\p{L}{0,250}$` pattern allows strings only containing Unicode (base) letters from 0 to 250 occurrences. Change to `{1,250}` to disallow empty values.